# Xcode bug when displaying an xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I'm currently using Xcode 7.1 and I came across this:

[image: xcode screen capture]

I'm in no case a seasoned Mac user and I'm unable to revert to the full display where I had the project's info on the center of the screen.

Does someone more experienced or less dumb than me know how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you using git? I can imagine that the .xproj file could be in a dirty merge state and would stop the xml from inflating... ??

Comment: Yes I'm using git.

It may be the cause of the bug, but it's been a long time since I merged the repository.

Comment: Okay, nvm. Just a thought.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of following but it was the case. Do you want to post your comment as a response so I can validate it ?

Comment: Please see the answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've seen this before, it's largely because of the .pbxproj file being corrupted - and this only really happens (??) if there is something that is externally modifying it, like a git merge.

In order to verify - and fix it - you need to:

a) Go to the project in Finder (and then close it in Xcode)

[image]

b) Ctrl-click it and select 'Show Package Contents'

[image]

c) open the project.pbxproj file in a text editor and finally

[image]

d) fix any information that is stopping Xcode from reading the XML structure and displaying it properly in the IDE.

[image]

With git, the error is usually unmergeable differences in the Build Settings - Teams, Profiles, Id's, etc. So you can either scroll very carefully through all 500+ lines of markup, or simply search for the git HEAD markers that look like chains of < or > lines - eg. '*<<<<<<<<<<< HEAD* '

Remove those, fix the conflicts, save the file, and reopen the Project. 
Should be all good then!